# Reading, writing and control dynamic instantiated HTML web table using python selenium

Tags: python, selenium, web-crawler

Assume that there are some specific searcher which search some goods, and I search with 'Teddy'.
Number of total result is 140 and it is displayed in small table made of `<div>` for each row and column(row for each content, column for info of content), which has scroll bar. This shows me a good list up to 5 in single display(each content use 40px for their height), if I need to see more, I need to scroll down this table.

The HTML is seems like below if I see goods at 45th to 49th(45th content are at the top of current view).

```
<div class="table-body" style="height:200px">            // This contains scrollbar
    <div class="table-panel" style="height:5600px">
        <div class="ag-row" style="height:40px row="42"> // This is each row of goods
            <div class="name">Teddy</div>                // This is each column of good
            <div class="price">200</div>
            <input class="amount">0</input>              // Input text box for put amount of goods to buy
        </div>
        <div class="ag-row" style="height:40px row="43">
            <div class="name">Brown Bess</div>
            <div class="price">230</div>
            <input class="amount">0</input>
        </div>
        <div class="ag-row" style="height:40px row="44"> // <-- This is what I'am seeing at the top. 0 based row attribute
            <div class="name">Blue</div>
            <div class="price">280</div>
            <input class="amount">0</input>
        </div>
        <div class="ag-row" style="height:40px row="45">
            <div class="name">Scientist</div>
            <div class="price">400</div>
            <input class="amount">0</input>
        </div>
        <div class="ag-row" style="height:40px row="46">
            <div class="name">Mouse</div>
            <div class="price">120</div>
            <input class="amount">0</input>
        </div>
        <div class="ag-row" style="height:40px row="47">
            <div class="name">Hangover</div>
            <div class="price">150</div>
            <input class="amount">0</input>
        </div>
        <div class="ag-row" style="height:40px row="48"> // <-- This is what I'am seeing last.
            <div class="name">Building</div>
            <div class="price">420</div>
            <input class="amount">0</input>
        </div>
        <div class="ag-row" style="height:40px row="50">
            <div class="name">Park</div>
            <div class="price">60</div>
            <input class="amount">0</input>
        </div>
        <div class="ag-row" style="height:40px row="51">
            <div class="name">Coffee</div>
            <div class="price">160</div>
            <input class="amount">0</input>
        </div>
        <div class="ag-row" style="height:40px row="49">
            <div class="name">Juice</div>
            <div class="price">100</div>
            <input class="amount">0</input>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Also it is my imaginary code, real code is much more complicate due to it's style, attributes and scripts. I think it is enough to ask my subject.

I checked the behavior of this web page.
It only makes it's html near where I'am seeing. When I see near 100th content, it create html between 92nd ~ 108th -- how many it is instantiated is quite random. When I scroll down or up, it remove content far from current position and make new one for current screen.

And I need to parse that data and need to make some list-like data structure in python.
Cause it instantiate partial data depending on screen(precisely speaking, it seems like it uses scrollbar for checking where I am seeing)
I tried to control scrollbar and crop all data in html and remove duplicates. Codes are below

```
from selenium import webdriver
..blah..

def iterateOptionTable(driver):
    el_viewport = driver.find_element_by_class_name('table-body')
    driver.execute_script('document.getElementsByClassName("{}")[0].scrollTop = 0;'.format('table-body'))
    max_height = int(driver.execute_script('return document.getElementsByClassName("{}")[0].scrollHeight;'.format('table-body')))
    scrolling_amnt = int(40 * 5) # Each row height is 40
    cur_scroll = 0
    table = defaultdict(int) # Don't put into list which is already pushed
    ret = []
    while cur_scroll < max_height:
            el_products = el_viewport.find_elements_by_xpath('./div/*')
            for el_p in el_products:
                rownum = int(el_p.get_attribute("row"))
                if rownum not in table:
                    table[rownum] = True
                    ret.append(el_p)
            yield ret   # List of WebElement of good
            ret.clear()        
            cur_scroll += scrolling_amnt
            driver.execute_script('document.getElementsByClassName("{}")[0].scrollTop = {};'.format('table-body', cur_scroll))

def parseElementToData(elems):
    ret = []
    for el in elems:
        single_data = DO_EXTRACT_DATA_FROM_EL()
        ret.append(single_data)

def parseTable(driver):
    ret = []
    for elems in iterateOptionTable(driver):
        data += parseElementToData(elems)
    return ret
```

There are several other jobs for the page, it is programmed using `yield` due to webpage hierarchy.

It pretty works well in debugger when I execute one by one. But in real runtime, it dose not even scroll down it's table. Not to mention that it is inefficient I think.
Also tried same version of Javascript by executing script from selenium.

Is there are more sophisticated way or can I get a answer for why these are not working in normal situation.
I'm quite new to web crawling and selenium.
Please Help :)

Comment: Also, there are text edit box row for each column, and I need to edit that box. Can you take account in this too?

Comment: can you share you url?

Comment: @KunduK Sorry, it is private property which need certification method. I cannot provide them.

Comment: I think I should let you know that the table can contain more than 1000 with other complicated component in page and developers of that web site are in capable of optimization for their web site. I strongly assume that it is because of some optimization algorithm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I failed to what I intended to.
Scrolling is not well interactable in such condition.
I managed to solve this via selecting single cell in table and send 'Keys.DOWN' button for scrolling down.

Answer (score 0):

The fact that you can see the elements or not does not mean that they are already in the HTML, they must have display: hidden until you scroll to them.

Now I am assuming here since you did not provide the link of the webpage in question and I'll try to explain with the code you provided.

What I suggest is to return all the rows from the table 1 by 1:

```
i = 0
row_list = []

while True:
    try:
        name = driver.find_element_by_xpath(x_path_to_the_row[i]/div).get_attribute('innerHTML'
        price = driver.find_element_by_xpath(x_path_to_the_row[i]/div[2]).get_attribute('innerHTML')
        row_list.append((name, price))
    except NoSuchElementException:
        break
    i += 1
```

Basically loop until the element of the table does not exist, get the columns of that row and construct a tuple holding both elements.

Note: Unless the HTML is inside a Shadow DOM component it should not be a problem.

Comment: Do you mean `display:none`? It should be seen in selenium object or web browser html viewer as I knew. What I mean is `find_element_by_xpath('./*)` returns only 10~ 14 WebElement out of 140. Can you specify more? Also I tried BeautifulSoup, it also did not crop least of content (least 126 goods)

Comment: I'm on the crawling task for 10 web sites, and other website which seems same works well.(I don't need to consider scrollbar or instantiation either, my codes were almost similar with you.) It is unique situation in specific web site. Also I think I need to tell you that this website has enormous connection traffic more than you can imagine.